# Type Text Into Terminal From Text File Using Python

Tags: python, file, text, command-line

I am new to python. I want to write a script that types in the first line of a text file into a terminal and then the second and so on. I have 2 questions. My first question is what command should I use to type into the terminal? I have not been able to find the answer to this. My other question is how can I input the first line of the text file, and then use the next line the next time through and so on? Sorry if these questions are to simple.

Comment: You can use the `pyautogui` library to emulate typing.

Comment: When you say "type into the terminal", do you mean it should run in the background and enter the text while the user is also able to enter text? Or do you mean you just want to execute each line of the file one at a time, *as if* they were typed into the terminal?

Comment: I want it to run in the background and enter text while the user is also able to enter text.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.